# React Native Navigator always displays the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using Stack based navigation.

My Navigator looks like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AddItemsScreen" component={AddItemsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The `Home` screen is rendered by default. At the bottom of the following component, there is a button to navigate to the `AddItemsScreen`:

```
function EntriesList({db, setDb, path, entries}) {
  const AddButtonPress = (event) => {
    navigation.navigate('AddItemsScreen', { db: db, setDb: setDb, path: path, entries: entries })
  }

  const entryListItems = [];
  for (const [idx, entry] of entries.entries()) {
    if (entry.type == "container") {
      entryListItems.push(<li key={idx}><EntryListItem_ContainerType entry={entry}></EntryListItem_ContainerType></li>)
    } else if (entry.type == "item") {
      entryListItems.push(<li key={idx}><EntryListItem_ItemType entry={entry}></EntryListItem_ItemType></li>)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{entryListItems}</ul>
      <Button onPress={AddButtonPress} title="Add Items"></Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `AddItemScreen` itself is very simple right now:

```
function AddItemsScreen(props) {
  const BackButtonPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', { name: 'Jane' })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onPress={BackButtonPress} title={props.route.params.path}></Button>
      <Text>Items screen</Text>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The problem is, when I click the "Add Items" button, the Home page is still getting rendered. The URL changes to "/AddItemsScreen" but the content never actually shows. Not sure what I need to fix, and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out using question [React-navigation change url but not view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67572372/react-navigation-change-url-but-not-view)

I needed to add `linking` attribute like so:

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['http://localhost:19006/']
};

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AddItemsScreen" component={AddItemsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Not sure if this is just needed because I'm developing on web.